# JSF GAE: Value Update Problem in managed bean method

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf, primefaces

I have the following piece of code with a simple `h:outputText` pointing to a `int` and a `p:commandLink` to set a value:

```
<h:form id="f1">
  <h:outputText id="text" value="#{testBean.index}"/>
  <p:commandLink actionListener="#{testBean.test}" update="text">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{testBean.index}" value="5" />
    <h:graphicImage url="/images.png"/>
  </p:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

The managed bean looks like this:

```
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean @ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable{
  private int index; // getter/setter

  @PostConstruct public void init() {
    index = 0;log.log(Level.WARNING, "@PostConstruct");}

  public void test(ActionEvent ae){
    log.log(Level.WARNING, "Index: "+index);}
}
```

The bean is constructed correctly, and after the first click on the image the `h:ouputText` is updated to *5*. But in my log message I only see `Index: 0` during the first click on the image.

It's something similar like [Jsf updates model value with old value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408376), but I have the JSF `@ManagedBean` annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action listeners are invoked in the order they're definied in the view. You want to use `action` instead of `actionListener`. Even more, the `action` should in first place have been used to invoke a business action.

```html
<p:commandLink action="#{testBean.test}" update="text">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{testBean.index}" value="5" />
    <h:graphicImage url="/images.png"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382)

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the `test` ActionEvent is getting fired before the request values have been applied.

To get a better understanding of the JSF phase lifecycle and when lifecycle events and ActionEvents fire, implement the Debug PhaseListener as specified in the following blog article.

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html

This should help you understand when request values are being applied, and when events are being fired.

Comment: This is actually not true. The `f:setPropertyActionListener` doesn't send a request parameter. It's just another action listener.